# SSIS How to read and convert data to currency type?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm, currency, kingswaysoft

I have the following JSON source file

```
[
  {
    "AccountNumber": 123456,
    "Balance": 745.000283
  },
  {
    "AccountNumber": 895686,
    "Balance": 0.241000
  },
  {
    "AccountNumber": 789876,
    "Balance": -.000125
  }
]
```

How to read and convert "Balance" value to currency type?

I use SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365 from KingswaySoft. I read the json file with the `JSON source` component. Default the component reads the `Balance` value as "float". Tried set data type as `decimal`, as `currency`, as a string followed by a conversion to `decimal`, conversion to `currency` etc.

But result always the one...

Instead of `745.000283` I get `745000283`

Instead of `0.241000` I get `241`

Comment: Please provide more details. How you are reading the JSON file? can you provide a screenshot of the package... Also `I tried every possible` what did you tried. Be more specific

Comment: Before asking your first question, it is recommended to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com) to learn more about asking good questions, accepting answers and other website rules. Also to get your the *"informed"* badge.

Comment: @Hadi 
Thanks for the answer!!!
I use SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365 from KingswaySoft.
I read the json file with the "json source" component.
Default the component reads the "Balance" value as "float".
Tryed set data type as "decimal", as "currency", as a string followed by a conversion to "decimal", conversion to "currency" etc.
But result always the one...
Instead of 745.000283 i have 745000283 value.

Comment: Related read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30249406/7920473

Comment: This is strange, we were not able to reproduce the issue on our side. Can you please reach out to us using our official support channel so that we can have a look of the situation with you remotely? You can find our contact information on our website at http://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us. Thanks!