# How to model decimal type in RAML

Tags: currency, raml

I am modelling a *REST API* using **RAML**. The response body of an endpoint (`JSON` format) is a financial transactions list. Each transactions contains an amount of money: currency and numeric value. The following is the snippet of my `RAML file`, please note the property `amount` in the `Transaction` type:

```
  # %RAML 1.0
  title: Trading details API
  version: v1
  mediaType: application/json
  baseUri: http://my.host.io/api/trading/v1/
  types:
    Transactions:
      type: Transaction[]
      minItems: 1
    Transaction:
      type: object
      properties:
        refNum:
          type: string 
        amount:
          type: ????
        currency:
          type: string
          minLength: 2
          maxLength: 3

  /trades
    get:
      description: Get details for a given trade
      queryParameters:
        userId:
          type: integer
          required: true

      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: Transactions
```

Unfortunately ***RAML*** has no Built-in `decimal` type, and the other numeric types (integer, float or double) are not suitable for this scope, mainly because I need to specify the number of digits after the `.` .

So question is: in **RAML** how do I correctly model the type `amount`?

I need to provide an exact definition of the type for each response body values, because this file will be the contract between the backend and frontend (developed by 2 different teams).

Any helps is welcomed.

*Please note that* I made some research on SO, and the closest question to mine is: [How to define money amounts in an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341337/how-to-define-money-amounts-in-an-api)
. But it is not related to RAML modelling, and the answers are not helping to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months I come back to share my experience.

The way I worked around it was by using the type `string` and a pattern. *I am aware of the many concerns around changing the data type* from `number` to `string`, but this approach is elegant, robust, flexible and still simple to test and understand.

The API consumers are forced to format the amount in the correct way and the messages coming in and out of the API are consistent, consistency cannot be guaranteed by using `multiplyOf` `0.0001` (where `25` and `25.0000` are both accepted).

I reused over and over this solution with great results. Therefore I am sharing this with the community.

Solution:

```
   [...]
   amount:
     type: string
     pattern: "^(([1-9][0-9]*)|[0])[.]([0-9]{4})$"
     currency:
       type: string
          ...
```

The pattern accepts `4 digits` on the decimal part, forces to use a `.` and the amount **cannot** starts with `0`, with the exception of `0.xxxx` family of numbers.

The following is an examples list of ***accepted*** numbers:

```
1.0000
54.0000
23456.1234
1.9800
0.0000
0.0001
```

Instead the following is an example list of ***rejected***:

```
0123.3453
12.12
1.1
000
01.0000
1.0
1.00
4.000
```

Moreover, you can specify the max number of digits on the left side (in this example `10`):

```
pattern: "^(([1-9][0-9]{0,9})|[0])[.]([0-9]{4})$"
```

Example of *accepted* numbers:

```
1234567890.1234
3.5555
0.1234
```

Example of *rejected* numbers:

```
12345678901.1234
123456789012.1234
```

Comment: I'm not sure this pattern is correct:
pattern: "^(([1-9][0-9]*)|[0])[.]([0-9]{4})$"
This shouldn't accept 0.xxxx numbers because the first block isn't optional.  This should fix it:
pattern: "^(([1-9]?[0-9]+)|[0])[.]([0-9]{4})$"
but then it won't restrict 0xx.xxxx numbers..
I think you'd have to use like a look ahead or look behind to fully disallow leading 0s except when followed by a dot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GeoffPotter 
Actually your patter allows 000[....].XXXX Which is not what I meant to have. The first part of the pattern is ^((_<something>_)**|[0]**)[.]. Emphasis is on "...|[0]" which means: either a digit starting with a number [1-9] *OR* a _single_ digit of Zero.

Which was the initial aim of the pattern

Answer (score 1):

RAML has a [similar construct](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#number) to the one in JSON Schema. You'll want to use `type: number` in combination with `multipleOf` to describe decimal precision.

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: number
multipleOf: 0.01
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I was thinking about adopting your solution, that in general tackle the problem we are trying to solve in this question. Unfortunately, by using `multipleOf` you cannot enforce to include decimal positions. For instance, **`25.00`** and **`25`** are both accepted. If it is acceptable with the model you are designing, your solution is **great**. On the contrary, if you want to enforce to accept only the first one (`25.00`), the _facet_ `multipleOf` does not help. I was after this second scenario.
Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Not to dismiss your concern but wouldn't most programming languages cast `25` to `25.00`? why not have the API allow it then?

Comment: In my point of view a good API designing solution define the body messages to be consistent across the entire API, regardless the programming language representation that the specific micro-service is using. 

Moreover, if you use Java you don't want to represent amount (decimal) with double due to the well known bugs of JVM. This is the reason why they introduced `BigDecimal`, which recommended constructor is `new BigDecimal(String)`.

However a good design must be free from languages constraint. Thanks for your appreciated contribution.